# storing the value of dynamically created textbox in session

Tags: asp.net

I have done a project in ASP.Net that asks to input a number in textbox. After typing a number in it and click a button it generates the number of textbox according to the value given in the textbox. Like if I type 5 in the textbox it dynamically generates 5 textboxes below.

I want all the value of dynamically created textbox(more than one textbox) to be stored in session and pass to next page through session after clicking another button. But i could not do that.

How can i solve this problem.
Anyone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array with the values and store that in the session. Code below is untested, but should give you an idea.

```
string[] arrayTextboxes = new string[numberOfTextboxes];
int index = 0;
foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
         arrayTextboxes[index] = ((Textbox)ctrl).Text;
         index++;
    }
}

Session["tbValues"] = arrayTextboxes;
```

Comment: This would pull the static text box as well, would it not?

Comment: Yes it would. You could create an ID for the static boxes and none for the dynamic ones. Then use `if (ctrl.ID == null)` or some sort of similar check to differentiate between your static and dynamic textboxes.